# Why is (function(){return this}).bind('abc')()==='abc' equals to false?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a function like that:

```js
var f1=function(){
   return this;
};
console.log(f1.bind('abc')()==='abc');
```

as I know, f1.bind('abc') should create a new function that returns 'abc', so I guess it should have output same as

```
console.log('abc'==='abc')
```

which is true, but now the output is false, what's wrong with my guess?

Comment: `===` means same value & same variable type `console.log(typoeof f1.bind('abc')(), typoeof 'abc')`

Comment: `typeof f1.bind('abc')()` is `object` and `typeof 'abc'` is `string` and strict comparison fails in this scneario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In non-strict mode, the primitive values are wrapped in *Object*. So, `'abc'` becomes `new Object('abc')`.

In strict mode, this does not happen.

```js
'use strict';

var f1 = function() {
  return this;
};
console.log(f1.bind('abc')() === 'abc');
```

Quoting from ES6 Specifications for [strict mode](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-of-ecmascript)

> If `this` is evaluated within strict mode code, then the `this` value is not coerced to an object. A this value of `null` or `undefined` is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects. The `this` value passed via a function call (including calls made using `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`) do not coerce the passed this value to an object (9.2.1.2, 19.2.3.1, 19.2.3.3).

Answer (score 4):

f1.bind('abc') is returning `String object` and 'abc' type is `string`.
so === giving false as it is comparing object to string.

```js
var f1=function(){
   return this;
};
console.log(typeof(f1.bind('abc')()));
console.log(typeof('abc'));
```